# Filtering JSON with System.Data.SQLite and json_each()

Tags: c#, sqlite

A SQLite database contains a column with JSON data like the following:

```
MyTable
______________________________________
| specs         | name   | date
--------------------------------------
| ["foo","bar"] | Test01 | 2018-02-05
| ["foo","bar"] | Test02 | 2018-02-01
| ["foo"]       | Test03 | 2018-02-03
```

Pseudo-code:

```
private static SQLiteConnection _sqliteDb;

using (var source = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source={databasePath};Version=3;"))
{
    source.Open();

    _sqliteDb = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
    _sqliteDb.Open();

    // copy db file to memory
    source.BackupDatabase(_sqliteDb, "main", "main", -1, null, 0);
    source.Close();
}

var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, _sqliteDb);
```

In order to filter on this column, the query looks like this:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable, json_each(MyTable.specs) AS spec WHERE spec.value = 'bar'"
```

This error appears: `SQLite error (1): no such table: json_each`

How to use json1 extension with [System.Data.SQLite.Core](https://system.data.sqlite.org)?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions [here](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach)?

Comment: Yes, my query is similar to the one in **4.13.1. Examples using json_each()**

Comment: Is `specs` the table name or the column name? (The other one is missing from the query.)

Comment: It is a column name. I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SQLite extensions weren't loaded.**

Right after:

```
_sqliteDb.Open();
```

I must call the following in order to make `json1` to work:

```
_sqliteDb.EnableExtensions(true);
_sqliteDb.LoadExtension("SQLite.Interop.dll", "sqlite3_json_init");
```

Also note that functions are registered per-connection.

Comment: The LoadExtension is failing to find that dll. What could be the problem?